# Hot Reload not working despite default settings in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

Hot reload does not work for me in a new default mvc web app.

Native code debugging is off. As specified in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022).

VS settings are all default.
Running the app with debugging in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment variable COR_ENABLE_PROFILING from 1 to 0 fixes this issue.

You can check current value in cmd using:

> echo %COR_ENABLE_PROFILING%